# Jetty does not recognize Solr installation as a context, what's wrong?

Tags: java, apache, solr, jetty, centos5

Sorry for the vague question but I'm newbie in CentOs and Solr
I have installed Java, Jetty and Solr, I start the Solr with:
`java -jar start.jar` in the examples folder of the solr I have put in my CentOS box and it says :

```
2010-10-13 13:12:41.623::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2010-10-13 13:12:41.842::INFO:  jetty-6.1.3
2010-10-13 13:12:41.913::INFO:  Started SocketConnector @ 0.0.0.0:8983
```

but when I visit mydomain:[jetty port] , there are no contexts listed.

Comment: Have you searched for this on serverfault.com? IMHO, It is off-topic on stackoverflow.com. E.g. http://serverfault.com/questions/94238/how-to-install-apache-solr-java-on-centos

Answer (score 0):

Try visiting `http://mydomain:8983/solr`

Comment: Thnx
But the url works *if* solr is recongnized by the jetty, apparently jetty does not recognize my solr installation, visting the mention the url says: `HTTP ERROR: 404

NOT_FOUND

RequestURI=/solr

Powered by jetty://`

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Pratik : it *is* an answer. The OP couldn't access http://mydomain:8983 but Solr by default uses http://mydomain:8983/solr . Thus my answer. Don't worry, I know very well what's an answer and what's a comment.

Comment: oh I hope you write some description your answer post then it would be better understanding for all and may be your answer could be acceptable by asked user

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It was Apache-Solr dev. The stable package did the trick.

Comment: Can you explain it?